# Send emails from a container in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, email, gitlab, postfix-mta

I am using a openSUSE Tumbleweed container in a gitlab ci pipeline which runs some script. In that script, I need to send an email at some point of time with certain content.

In the container, I am installing postfix and configuring that relay server in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

The following command works on my laptop using that same relay server:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject" -r sender@email.com receiver@email.com
```

but doesn't work from the container, even having the same postfix configuration.

I've seen some tutorials that show how to use the postfix/smtp configuration from the host, but since this is a container running in gitlab ci, that's not applicable.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting and note whether you're using the shared runners from gitlab, or hosting your own?

Comment: Shared runners in my gitlab's company domain. There is actually no error, the command succeeds and returns 0 even, but there is no email sent at all...

Comment: Depending on where your gitlab runners are running data-center-wise, many cloud providers block outbound SMTP traffic. Since the `mail` utility uses a SMTP server, it's possible that the outbound traffic is either being blocked per these rules, or the local SMTP server is no configured to send outbound emails. Since no error is thrown, those would be the first two places to look.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any other way to send emails without auth different than smtp that might work from any kind of runners?

Comment: There is a good blog post about this on Medium https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/send-gitlab-ci-reports-artifacts-via-e-mail-86bc96e66511 , recommending Mailgun. I've used them in the past and been generally pleased, but I've never personally tried integrating it with GitLab. Since you're just making a `curl` request, you're basically avoiding SMTP completely, which is usually a good bet.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I have found a simple way using python `smtplib` library.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so when people view the question in the future they know how you solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

So, finally opted for a python solution and call the script from bash, this way I really don't need to configure postfix, smtp or any other thing. You just export your variables in bash (our use argparse) and run this script. Of course, you need a relay server without auth (normally on port 25).

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

smtp_server = os.environ.get('RELAY_SERVER')
port = os.environ.get('RELAY_PORT')
sender_email = os.environ.get('SENDER_EMAIL')
receiver_email = os.environ.get('RECEIVER_EMAIL')

mimetext = MIMEText("this is the body of the email")
mimetext['Subject'] = "this is the subject of the email"
mimetext['From'] = sender_email
mimetext['To'] = receiver_email

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email.split(','), mimetext.as_string())
```